# method cheaper not calling in main

Tags: java

I made a method cheaper and when I tried to call it in my main, its not outputting anything. Am I calling it correctly or am I doing something wrong?

```
package cwk18;

public class Cwk18 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    StoreItem bill = new StoreItem();
    bill.setName("bill");
    bill.setPrice(7);
    bill.cheaper(bill);   
}
}
```

This is my main code, where  I am using bill (storeitem) to call the method cheaper.

```
package cwk18;

import java.util.Collections;

public class StoreItem {
    private String name;
    private double price;

    public StoreItem(){ // constructor
        name= "name unavailable";
        price = 4;
    }
    public StoreItem(String naming1,int val){ // parameterized construtor
        this();
        setName(naming1);
        setPrice(val);
    }
    public String getName(){ //name accessor
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String newName){ // name mutator
        this.name = newName;
    }
    public double getPrice(){ // price accessor
        return this.price;
    }
    public void setPrice(int val){// price mutator
            this.price = val;
    }
    public StoreItem cheaper(StoreItem newItem){ 
        if (this.price > newItem.getPrice()){
            return newItem;
        }else {
            return this;
        }
    }
```

}

This is the Class StoreItem that has the cheaper method in it.

Comment: I cannot see any print statements.

Comment: The returns in the StoreItem class are the print statements

Comment: @Brandon No, returns are not print statements.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an output. But no way to see. Try:

```
System.out.println(bill.cheaper(bill).toString());
```

Comment: The OP's `StoreItem` may need to `Override` the  `toString()` method.